# error when following tutorial of deploying jsf2.1 application on google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, jsf-2, web-config

I followed this tutorial to create an application with jsf and deploy it on google app engine but even if I followed all steps of the tuto

I encountoured this error :

```
    18 avr. 2013 01:01:10 com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\Users\user\Desktop\eclispe_workspace\test_google\war\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
18 avr. 2013 01:01:10 com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\Users\user\Desktop\eclispe_workspace\test_google\war\WEB-INF/web.xml
18 avr. 2013 01:01:10 com.google.appengine.tools.development.SystemPropertiesManager setSystemProperties
INFO: Overwriting system property key 'java.util.logging.config.file', value 'C:\Users\user\Downloads\Compressed\eclipse-jee-juno-SR2-win32\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.7.1\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.7.1\config\sdk\logging.properties' with value 'WEB-INF/logging.properties' from 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\eclispe_workspace\test_google\war\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml'
18 avr. 2013 01:01:10 com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
18 avr. 2013 01:01:11 com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: jetty-6.1.x
18 avr. 2013 01:01:11 com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
ATTENTION: failed com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@14ab51b{/,C:\Users\user\Desktop\eclispe_workspace\test_google\war}: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/sun/faces/config/WebConfiguration : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
18 avr. 2013 01:01:11 com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
ATTENTION: failed JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler@e8606c: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/sun/faces/config/WebConfiguration : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
18 avr. 2013 01:01:11 com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
ATTENTION: Error starting handlers
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/sun/faces/config/WebConfiguration : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.
```

do you have any idea

thank you

Comment: you couldn't deploy Java code with JVM Bytecode target = 1.7, try target = 1.6

Comment: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError happens because of a higher JDK during compile time and lower JDK during runtime

Comment: @thank you you are right, it works with 1.6

Comment: ok, i will post as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError happens because of a higher JDK during compile time and lower JDK during runtime.
You couldn't deploy Java code with JVM Bytecode target = 1.7, please try target = 1.6